# Button Keeps Vanishing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton

My App Basically has a start screen where the user enters how many exercise reps they want to do. I use this as my max variable, and then I have a button which activates a counter mechanism which adds up to max value. When it equals max value, the UI resets and I am meant to get back to Screen 1.

I have been working this problem for over an hour and I can't figure out why my button doesn't reappear when the clicker value = user input(max value).
I have coded it to do so in

`ButtonScreen1.hidden = false
UserInputScreen1.hidden = false
LabelScreen1.hidden = false`

But the Button won't reappear. But it appears at the start, so it's not a view controller issue to my knowledge.

[Images (Top One Is Without Button which Should be Present at the End of the Application) (Bottom One is What It Looks like as it Starts which I am trying to replicate at the End)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq9aZ.jpg)

[For Full Code](http://pastebin.com/CZgWtMbF)

Comment: What happens instead of the button reappearing?

Comment: It just vanishes, I get a screen without the button where it should be. But it works when I start it up...

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/KQOjR (After Above) (Before Below)

Comment: You should post some of your relevant code

Comment: Sorry, I am a noob to iOS development. Isn't the code linked above relevant?